# What is the difference between a native heap and a Java heap

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

What is the difference between a native heap and a Java heap? I saw a post that meant the jvm was in the native heap. I feel wrong, but I don't understand, but I feel wrong. If any of you know this. I'd like you to take two minutes to answer my question. Thank you very much.

I looked for a lot of information on the Internet, but I didn't find the answer I wanted.

Comment: The java heap refers to heap memory managed by the JVM, these are things the java runtime tracks and potentially garbage collects. The native heap would be heap memory not managed by the JVM (native heap is a new term to me though, off-heap is generally what this kind of memory is called). The two often appear in the context of FFI through JNI/JNA or the new Panama project.

Comment: The term “native heap” only makes sense in the context of a native language having such a concept. So a JVM implemented in such a language has a native and so do native code fragments executed within the JVM, e.g. via JNI or FFI. But there is no requirement that a JVM has to be implemented in such a language or hast to support such native code.